# Why do we do a POST to confirm deletion in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-2

The following is a note from **Professional ASP.NET MVC 2** by Scott Hanselman ++

> You might ask — why did we go through
>   the effort of creating a <form> within
>   our Delete Confi rmation screen? Why
>   not just use a standard hyperlink to
>   link to an action method that does the
>   actual delete operation? The reason is
>   because we want to be careful to guard
>   against Web-crawlers and search
>   engines discovering our URLs and
>   inadvertently causing data to be
>   deleted when they follow the links.
>   HTTP-GET-based URLs are considered
>   safe for them to access/crawl, and
>   they are supposed to not follow
>   HTTP-POST ones. A good rule is to make
>   sure that you always put destructive
>   or data-modifying operations behind
>   HTTP-POST requests.

If web-crawlers and search engine have no access to the page containing deletion button, is it safe to use a standard hyperlink to link to an action method doing the actual delete operation?

Comment: Why did they choose the POST method when there are a DELETE http method? I mean, they did go through the hassle to use POST instead of GET. It's no more complex to use the DELETE than POST.

Comment: Answering my own comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good rule of thumb is that GET shouldn't change data.  If you want to change some data you use POST.

That is why ScottHa etc used a form to submit the delete.  If it doesn't work for your app you can use GET if needed.

Alternatively you could use JavaScript to submit the form whe the user clicks link.

Comment: Correct, any GET request should not have side effects (this is called idempotence). Also, if you use a link to delete something, redirect after the delete is done and the user hits back, they won't be prompted to re-submit the action again. But as far as the original question goes, you can safely use a link if no search engine will hit it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's safe if a search engine can't reach it. But make sure to include some sort of confirmation or undo function. Links are easy to mis-click.

Comment: providing undo after committing deletion will be hard, right?

Comment: Rather than actually deleting the record from the database, set a field such as 'deleted' to true.  Only show those items who's 'deleted' flag is false.  You can set this flag to false again to undo.

Comment: @Michael, If don't delete rows, and define a "IsDeleted" column for all tables in my database, I will make me do more job such as doing deleted mark cascade rule whenever the parent table row is marked as deleted.

Comment: Remember that javascript confirmations on links (`onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"` will not work with spiders.

Comment: @xport - yep will result in more work.  Gotta assess the trade off - is it something users need? Is it going to add value?  If not, don't do it.  In our app, trust is a huge deal so we never really delete anything.  Our users aren't scared of clicking buttons, cos they know they can 'undo' anything.

Answer (score 2):

I would add what even if admin page is protected by password, delete links could be "clicked" by some locally installed web accelerator software. So using POST method is safer.

Comment: @alexander, how can we make a get request for a password protected page? it sounds interesting for me!

Comment: @xport - the same way you make a GET request for a non-password-protected page.

Comment: @Andrew, is it really possible? I have not known it before.

Comment: @xport - that would be because you are not aware that a page being password protected has nothing at all to do with what HTTP method you use to access it.

Comment: @Andrew, my terminology of "password protected pages" means only successfully authenticated users can access the pages. I hope we have the same understanding of this term first.

Comment: @xport - your web sites must be fascinatingly (and needlessly) complex, if password-protected pages can not be accessed via GET...

Comment: @Andrew, shortly speaking, can you view someone's paypal page? It is just an example. I don't know whether we are talking the same things. Sorry.

Comment: Yes; mine. Via GET requests, after I log in. Why do you think GET requests don't work for password protected pages? Where do you get that idea from? It's just plain incorrect.

Comment: @Andrew, after authenticated, it is a different story :)

Comment: @xport - Umm... now it's my turn to ask you; Do you know what "authenticated" means? *Of course* you have to be authenticated to view a page that requires you to be authenticated... dare I say, "Duh". But again: That has *nothing at all* to do with whether you use GET requests or not.

Comment: @Andrew, I am who I said I am. My turn: If you haven't been authenticated using my credential, is your effort  harmfull to make a Get request to my paypal page for example?

Comment: @Andrew, I go home now and will be back 2 hours later.

Comment: @xport - No, it's not 'harmful'. You *really* need to find yourself a basic HTTP guide to read or something; you don't seem to be able to grasp even the basic relationships between things involved.

Comment: @Andrew, if you are not logged in as an admin for example, how can you click the delete hyperlink on the admin page? you cannot access the page right?

Comment: @xport - Duh. But if the `Delete` is a simple hyperlink, guess what; XSRF! But what about the page that you are viewing that link on in the first place? Even THAT page requires you to be authenticated. Yet, you probably view that page with a simple GET request. **Bam!** There you have it: A GET request for a password-protected page. It's like fairy-dust magic! So beautiful....

Comment: @xport - Seriously; you aren't getting it at all. This isn't helping. Read up in that book about XSRF; it will tell you how someone can even make you "click" a GET link *while you are logged in* from your own browser, without you even knowing. Maybe look up "Confused Deputy" attacks, CSRF/XSRF, etc.

Comment: @Andrew, I am figuring out what XSRF is first.

Comment: @Andrew, I think we are talking slightly two different things. I am talking about a situation where you have ABSOLUTELY no access to my protected pages. Or more precisely, you have no chance to do exploitation. How can you make a GET request? We are out of sync. But I admit your info about XSRF is helpful! Thanks for that!

Comment: @xport - My info on XSRF is only helpful if you understand it. Which you clearly do not - otherwise you would not have asked that question. XSRF vulnerabilities are precisely about me making *you* do a GET request via your own login, for me. It's as simple as posting a stray `<img>` tag on a site I know you visit all the time, the `src` of which points to a GET url that *you* will be logged in and authorized to request, and you'll never know I did it. The simplest solution is to maintain those idempotent GETs.

Comment: @Andrew, I have read and understand how CSRF works. It works only when you can exploit my session which is beyond the scope of my question. :)

Comment: @xport - Whatever you say. Give me the URL of your first public site sometime, and I'll demonstrate just how little you understand. Otherwise, I'm done here.

Comment: @Andrew, I will ask you to exploit my testing site, hopely finished 2 months from now :) I promise!

Comment: Of course I will provide you with a "private or password-protected" page containing a hyperlink to delete my records or more extremely to drop my database.

Answer (score 2):

If you use GET requests to do any changes to your database at all, you will more than likely get hit with Cross-Site Request Forgery attacks at some point. The book you are reading discusses that more, and I have a few posts about it on my blog. It's an extremely common vulnerability I find these days; as frequent as SQL Injection, and *much simpler* to exploit.

Comment: OK. I will figure out your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good reason not to use GET for operations which change data. It's not just for semantic purity. http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/30/simple-jquery-delete-link-for-asp.net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score -1):

@xport: POST take 2 times to executed one action, and GET only take 1 time. In POST, the first time, it will contact to server for authenticate action, and after that it will executing this action. In GET situation, it only call to action that not authenticate. So in usual, POST spend more time to execute action than GET (2 round trips). If you have some actions as DELETE, UPDATE, ADD,... you must execute it with POST and if some actions only select data from database, only GET. That is my understand in GET and POST.

Comment: @ThangChung - Your understanding of GET and POST is not correct.

Comment: I think I wrong when explain about message authentication.  The difference between "GET" and "POST" so that former means that form data is to be encoded (by a browser) into a URL while the latter means that the form data is to appear within a message body. http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html

Comment: "Authentication" has nothing to do with it; do away with that word when talking about GET or POST. Your comment above is basically correct, though worded clumsily. Your answer above, though, mentions things that aren't really related to the difference at all; such as authentication, POST being two requests, POST taking 'more time'. There are related grains of truth here or there, but a comment really can't elaborate on all of that.

Comment: *POST takes 2 times to execute one action* This is not strictly or necessarily true. In fact, the typical pattern is that a GET request happens first, and from that page a POST request is made. Strictly speaking - that is one GET and one POST... not POST taking two times. The essence of what you mean seems to be "you have to make an extra request to do a POST", but even that's not actually correct in this context: To submit the same data via GET in a typical scenario, you would ALSO need to first make another GET request, too.